# What are good settings for transcoding videos uploaded to my app?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am working on an app that allows users to share videos. The problem is that many videos are very high bitrate. For example, A 4-minute H264 video from an old iPhone is encoded at 1080p and runs ~17,000 kb/s (~500 megabytes). Accepting and distributing such videos at this bitrate/resolution is not practical for a social application.

I have been playing with ffmpeg to transcode videos to smaller sizes and higher compression, but have not achieved acceptable results. For example:

```
ffmpeg \
    -i in.mov \
    -vf scale=w='if(gt(iw\,ih)\,780\,-2)':h='if(gt(iw\,ih)\,-2\,780)' \ 
    -c:v libx264 \
    -crf 28 \
    -preset medium \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -movflags +faststart \
    out.mp4
```

This command transcodes the above-mentioned 500MB file down to 70MB. It scales the larger dimension of the video to 780 pixels and compresses the video quite a bit. The results are okay, but the file is still large.

Taking the longer dimension down to 480 pixels, the file is reduced to 40MB. Still quite large, and now significantly degraded. Also, the transcoding still takes quite a long time: about 1-1.5x on my 4 year old i7 Macbook Pro with 16GB RAM.

I'm not sure how to improve on this. H265 is not supported in browsers. I am wondering:

- How can I reduce size further?
- How can I transcode faster than 1x without significantly reducing quality? Even 2-3x doesn't seem great?

Is this as good as it gets?

Comment: Minor suggestion is to stream copy the audio if it is already AAC: `-c:a copy`. There may be other suggestions depending on the contents of the complete log from your command, but doubtful of anything of importance.

Comment: @llogan thanks, I was wondering about what to do with the audio stream... what's the advantage of specifying `-c:a copy`? That seems to be the default behavior?

Comment: `-c:a copy` will [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (copy and paste) the audio: otherwise it will re-encode to AAC for MP4 output which is slower and introduces [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss). Stream copy is not the default.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I misunderstood the default section over at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map. Will review again. Yeah, doesn't make sense to re-encode audio if it's 128kbs or less.

Comment: That particular wiki page is a mess and needs to be re-written. See [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) in the documentation.

Comment: Will do. Much appreciated.

Comment: The wiki page has been edited. Is it more clear?

Comment: Seems clear except I think if I had landed on this page with no prior knowledge on the subject, I'd still assume you re-mux by default. If you want that to be clearer on this wiki page, maybe mention it somewhere higher than the third example ("Using stream copy (re-mux) to avoid re-encoding")? It's pretty good as-is though?... can't have everything on one page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Is this as good as it gets?`

Yes. There is no such thing as a free lunch in video encoding.

You can speed up encoding if the machine has a hardware encoder like QuickSync on some intel CPUs, or nvenc on Nvidia Gpus (or videotoolbox on some Macs/iOS). But the file size will be the same, or even a little bigger.

Comment: Thanks. As I suspected. I still don't understand, though: let's say I torrent an 800MB feature film, `ffprobe` reports H264 at 855 kb/s in the video stream (1280x544), and the quality is quite good. Is such a result only achievable at very slow encoding (ie. multiple passes)? In my example above with the above command, the resulting bitrate is 2173 kb/s (438x780).

Comment: Can’t answer that as there are many variables that come into play. Resolution Frame rate, encoding settings, information density of the video, how “quality” is measured etc.